# DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, devtools

I am trying to use Python in automating my work which requires to open a web page and fill login details, but I am getting the following error:

> WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

**Code**:

[image: actual code]

**Error**:

[image: error shown]

**Then chrome crashes with the error**:

[image: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist]

What to do now?

Comment: Check [this][1] question, maybe your answer is here. [1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t

Comment: i tried without any success

Answer (score 0):

Please, try adding the next in your code:

```
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0' 
os.environ['XAUTHORITY']='/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
```

Remember that you must download the version of WebDriver in [this page of Google](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) according to the installed in your pc.